# Take advice OF or FROM

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the sentences is correct:

.**"You should take advice Of John."**

. **"You should take advice From John."**

I am not a native speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you can take John’s advice, which is the same as taking ***the*** advice of John. (But note that the “X of John” sounds very stilted) Or you can take advice from John.  Taking John’s advice is more likely when discussing some specific advice from John.  Your second option is more likeky when speaking in general about the typical quality of John’s advice.

Comment: Please specify US English or UK English, and please show what you found in a dictionary with usage examples, and where you got stuck on understanding what you found.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but they mean different things.

**'Take advice of'** (with no article before 'advice') is slightly old-fashioned British English meaning 'seek the opinion of'. One might, when faced with a difficult business situation, decide to take advice of a lawyer.

> We do recommend you take advice of your local healthcare team.
>
> We decide to take advice of another specialist in pneumatology,
>   suggested by Dr. Garrido
>
> 'With all resistant infections, GPs will take advice of local
>   microbiologist specialists when getting an assessment of best
>   antibiotics
>
> Before making any decisions take advice of a person whom you trust.

**"Take advice from"** means "willingly accept and act on advice from" someone.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are valid depending on what you are trying to say.  Your first example:

> You should take the advice of John.

(note the article "the," which is required) suggests that John has offered advice and a third party (the speaker) is verifying that it is good advice.  You can reword this sentence into the more common (and more comfortable):

> You should take John's advice.

which has the same meaning.

Your second example:

> You should take advice from John.

is a general statement that suggests John has not yet offered any advice, but when he does, he can be trusted.

Answer (score -1):

**Take the advice of John** means that he is a man who is giving advice and someone suggested you to take that advice.

But **Take the advice from John** means that he is not a person who offers advice but taking advice from him will help.